# Module for extracting information from remote site?

Tags: 7, entities, database

I want to give user better experience when filling in forms. They are prompted to fill information about some product, like price, description, image, etc...

My idea is that I'll let them just copy & paste URL to (for example) amazon and the website will itself pre-fill all the fields (price, description, ...).

So I would basically need set of regular expressions per field, per remote site. This is not a problem, I can cover 90% of our user daily used websites. If this mechanism fails, then user still will be able to fill the information manually.

My problem is that I cannot find any drupal module that is capable of doing something like this. Does anyone know how to (simply) achieve this goal? Or do I have to write a module for this?

Comment: for drupal 6? or drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

I think that Feeds [XPath Parser](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) and [Example Web Scraper](http://drupal.org/project/example_web_scraper) could be a guidance to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your approach would really work as it would require the scraper to be authenticated as your user with the target site.

It may be worth looking into [OAuth](http://drupal.org/project/oauth) or [Facebook Connect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect) to streamline your registration process.